# VB.NET: Detect if a text file is open

Tags: vb.net, text-files

Is there any way to determine if a text file is currently open in a text editor?  Or better yet, is there a way to trigger an event when a text file is opened (from any program)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I'll make a Timer that checks the last modified time of the file.... and when the program starts, it'll get the last modified time.

Comment: I am not sure why you'd want a timer in this situation, you haven't mentioned any re-occuring process. If you are interested in determining if the file has been saved during the time your program is running, I'd follow Tom's advise and go with the FileSystemWatcher

Comment: I want to know if a file has been opened (not necessarily saved) during the runtime of my program.  Thus, I can check every, say, 100 ms to see if the last modified timestamp has changed.  If it is, it is safe to say that the file has been opened within 100 ms time.

Comment: The modified timestamp will not tell if you a file has been opened - only if it was saved.

Comment: Couldn't I use: File.GetLastAccessTime()

Answer (score 5):

Using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) component you can detect Changed, Created, Deleted, and Renamed events statically.

If you want to detect Last Access you need to manually set the [NotifyFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx) to include [LastAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx).

Comment: Any idea what the NotifyFilter of LastAccess does in relation to FileSystemWatcher?  How would I use that?

Comment: If I set the NotifyFilter, I don't think it will invoke an event unless a Changed, Created, Deleted, or Renamed event occurs.  I guess LastAccess doesn't offer what I need.

Answer (score 1):

When most editors have a file open they typically follow a set strategy:
1. Open File
2.Read entire contents into buffer
3.Close File

Then *your* program runs.   Since the file is already closed, any attempts to open it will of course succeed.   Using a `FileSystemWatcher` this can be detected if a file is open or closed.   However, you will not be able to detect if the file has been open *prior* to your program running.

Comment: How would I detect if a file is opened while my program is running?

Comment: (My program will be running before they even open the file)

Comment: Even if you know the user opened the file into a buffer, I don't think FileSystemWatcher would tell you if the user has closed the buffer in the text editor. If you have some idea what text editor will be used you could try scanning the window list looking for a window titled something like "MyFile.txt - MyEditor" (won't work well with multi-tab editors) or looking for temporary files (e.g. vim creates .MyFile.swp). I [used this](https://github.com/gmatht/joshell/blob/master/scripts/git-sync-all.sh) idea to detect if an automated git-pull was safe.